# How to do unittesting in Ansible?

Tags: unit-testing, ansible

[One of the Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/test_strategies.html) indicates:

> Obviously at the development stage, **unit tests** are great too.

If I query for unit tests in the same document nothing is found. Is there for example an equivalent of rspec-puppet in Ansible?

Comment: You may want to look at ansible-review by the same author as ansible-lint. Serverspec will be your goto for end state tests like with any similar tool, although you may be able to get unit tests going with infrataster (this is like beaker from Puppet except better). You may also want to look at test-kitchen support for ansible, which seems to be ansible-kitchen upon googling.

Comment: I infer usage of Ansible roles when talking about unit testing.  Check out [molecule](https://github.com/metacloud/molecule) from MetaCloud.  They have both Vagrant and Docker providers to spin up infrastructure and apply your role.

Comment: molecule as suggested by @thankyour is the equivalent of rspec-puppet.

Comment: @thankyour please post this comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing spectests the easiest tool to use I have found is goss.  It is a single binary in golang.  It is super fast and the test is written in yaml.  It eliminates having to program for your testing and abstracts that.
https://github.com/aelsabbahy/goss

The author has a simple screen gif to show usage.

Comment: An example of how we use goss with Ansible can be found here [http://isbyr.com/using-goss-and-ansible-templates-for-system-testing/(http://isbyr.com/using-goss-and-ansible-templates-for-system-testing/)